# verification using monkey runner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

Consider this scenario:

1. You have a textbox in which you have to write some text "abcd"
2. Next you have to verify if the entered text belongs to the correct character set (like UTF - 8) or simply you have to verify that "abcd" has been entered into the text box

This was asked to me in an interview.I had to write a monkeyrunner script that could do the above mentioned two operations. 1st one was damn easy. Any comments on the 2nd one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient) this monkeyrunner script could be as simpler as

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.dtmilano.android.viewclient import ViewClient
...

device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()
s = "abcd"
device.type(s)
vc = ViewClient(device)
vc.dump()
editText = vc.findViewById("id/EditText") # if you don't know the id you can use vc.getViewIds()
if s == editText.mText():
   print "OK"
```